# Validations for Rails 4 Postgres Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, validation

Is it possible to use standard Rails validations with a Postgres array? I have a `service_area` column which accepts an array of zip codes. It works well enough, though when I try to use validations for numericality and length, the validators throw errors. Input such as `78702, 78704, 78705` gets the error messages `is not a number` and `is the wrong length`. It appears that Rails is trying to validate them as a string, rather than as an array of five digit zipcodes. Is there some way to inform the validator that it needs to parse the input as an array? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is there something stopping you from converting it to array explicitely like this?

```
"1, 2, 3".split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: The question would be how'd I'd send that array to the validators instead of the string.

Comment: Without viewing your code I can only recommend to try out postgres_ext gem.